# plotting abline with multiple regression in R

Tags: r

I am performing a multiple regression on 4 predictor variables and I am displaying them side-by-side... but I just cant figure out how to plot the abline whilst having them side-by-side. 
Just for clarity, here's my code:

```
fit1 <- lm(bband ~ ProfHH + Employed + TwoCars + HEQual, data = County)
layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), 2, 2, byrow = TRUE))  ## display 4 plots side by side
plot(bband ~ ProfHH +  Employed + TwoCars + HEQual, data = County)
```

[Image of the 4 plots side-by-side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya14T.png)

The problem Im having is I don't know how to add the abline whislt plotting them this way!? 
Normally I'd just use `abline(fit1)`but this is producing the following error:

```
"abline" is not a graphical parameter
```

Any suggestions as to how I'd fix this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to call plot function first then you can use `abline` like below:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$wt)
abline(lm(wt ~ mpg, mtcars))
plot(mtcars$disp,mtcars$wt)
abline(lm(wt ~ disp, mtcars))
```

The idea is to see the relationship between a dependent and independent variable so plot them first and then call abline with the regression formula. Also , the order matters in plot you will provide x as first argument and y as second and in abline's lm function the formula should be in order of `y ~ x` . In this case y is your dependent and x is your independent variable.